# SimpleSamlPhp; Default configuration not working - missing config file

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I cant get a default simplesamlphp installation running. I've downloaded the latest release (2.0.3) from the offical website and unzipped the folder to `C:\xampp\htdocs\myWebsite\simplesamlphp\`. Now when browsing `http://localhost/myWebsite/simplesamlphp/public/` I get:

`SimpleSAML\Error\CriticalConfigurationError: The configuration is invalid: The configuration (config/config.php) is invalid: Missing configuration file Backtrace: 1 public\_include.php:98 (require_once) 0 public\index.php:7 (N/A)`

Why doesnt it find the config file?

Comment: have you created a `C:\xampp\htdocs\myWebsite\simplesamlphp\config\config.php` file ?

Comment: I just have seen its called config.php.dist which has to be new I guess, havent seen something about it in the documentation and after renaming it to .php it works now.

Comment: It is a quite common practice to have sample configuration with another suffix. "just renaming it" is not a recommended approach. I would recommend that you read through and make sure that the configuration firs your needs. PHPmyadmin for example does something similar.
mysql and php also have "default configuration" where it is clearly stated that you should not "just use it in production"